# Bash script for uncompressing multiple files at a once

Tags: shell-script, compression

I have a set of files:

```
lium3@l128-37:/DATA/fr94/01 $ ls -l
total 7784
-rw-r--r-- 1 lium3 mcm1 395575 May  2  1996 fr940104.0z
-rw-r--r-- 1 lium3 mcm1 113815 May  2  1996 fr940104.1z
-rw-r--r-- 1 lium3 mcm1 186333 May  2  1996 fr940104.2z
-rw-r--r-- 1 lium3 mcm1 164854 May  2  1996 fr940105.0z
-rw-r--r-- 1 lium3 mcm1  39677 May  2  1996 fr940105.1z
-rw-r--r-- 1 lium3 mcm1 284948 May  2  1996 fr940105.2z
```

I wish to uncompress them all at once (this is just a sample!).

I tried this

```
find -name '*.0z' -exec sh -c 'uncompress  "${1%.*}" "$1"' _ {} \;
```

and just got:

```
gzip: ./fr940125.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: ./fr940125.0z: unknown suffix -- ignored
gzip: ./fr940106.gz: No such file or directory
gzip: ./fr940106.0z: unknown suffix -- ignored
```

I have many directories with files like these.

If I can get a script to do one directory, is it possible to do it recursively down through the directories?

Comment: When you say 'all at once', do you mean that you want the operation to be performed in parallel, using all cores of a multi-core machine? There does exist a program 'parallel' for that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two problems:

1: Your `${1%.*}` results in the basename of the files (e.g. `fr940125`), the uncompress therefore tries to add the default suffix .gz, for the combined new file name it tries, no file does exist.

2: you give a second parameter to uncompress, which is the correct file name of the archive, but uncompress does not know what to do with the file ending. Try to give the parameters '`-S .0z`' as argument.

The following command would maybe the right one, to recursively extract all .0z files in the current and all sub directories:

```
find -name '*.0z' -exec sh -c 'uncompress  -S .0z "$1"' _ {} \;
```